# How render twitter widgets for any profiles?

Tags: api, twitter, widget, feed, profile

Our site has many companies profiles. Each profile has own block with twitter feed.

So recently, it worked very simply:

```
<div style="text-align: center;" id="twtr-profile-widget"></div>
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/1/widget.js"></script>
<link href="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/1/widget.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
  new TWTR.Widget({
  // Some variables
  }).render().setProfile('<?php print $profile ?>').start();
</script>
```

But now, after changes in the Twitter's API I cannot do that.
Now code looks like below:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-widget-id="<?php print $widget_id ?>"></a>
<script>
  !function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
      js=d.createElement(s);
      js.id=id;
      js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
  }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Now we must use **widget-id** instead **Profile name**. 
It means that we have to generate separate widgets for each company or ask them about it!

The pain in the ass is that they have to add our site to widget's whitelist.

So my question is, **how can I render twitter widgets for any profiles?**